# How to change elements color with a click

Tags: javascript

I know this is basic. You'll have to excuse me. I'm a js student and I'm having such a hard time with an issue here.

So... I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RocketSeat - Challenge 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
        <button onclick="MakeSquare()" style="margin-top: 100px;">Make a square</button>

    </body>
    <script>
        function MakeSquare(){
            const square = document.createElement('div')
            const elementBody = document.querySelector('body')
            square.style.backgroundColor ='red'
            square.style.width = '50px'
            square.style.height = '50px'
            square.style.marginTop= '50px'
            square.setAttribute('onmouseover','getRandomColor()')
            elementBody.appendChild(square)
        }

        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            var color = "#";
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
                }
            square.style.backgroundColor = color // I know this is not gonna work - I just put here to give the idea. 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

As you can see, the button is creating squares.
Now - the issue that I'm having is that it is suppose to change the respective square backcolor as I hover it with my mouse. How could I do it? I have the function to give me a hexcolor but I don't know how to set the element color.

Comment: use CSS `:hover`. No need to use JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: PS, your question title states you're looking for a *click*, than in your question you're asking for *hover*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MakeSqaure` function do the following instead of the `setAttribute`:

```
square.addEventListener('mouseover', getRandomColor)
```

and then:

```
function getRandomColor( e ) {
  const letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Full thing:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RocketSeat - Challenge 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
        <button onclick="MakeSquare()" style="margin-top: 100px;">Make a square</button>

    </body>
    <script>
        function MakeSquare(){
            const square = document.createElement('div')
            const elementBody = document.querySelector('body')
            square.style.backgroundColor ='red'
            square.style.width = '50px'
            square.style.height = '50px'
            square.style.marginTop= '50px'
            square.addEventListener('mouseover',getRandomColor)
            elementBody.appendChild(square)
        }

        function getRandomColor( e ) {
            var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            var color = "#";
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
                }
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = color // I know this is not gonna work - I just put here to give the idea. 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @KajiyamaVK yw, just ask if you have some questions about how and why.

Answer (score 0):

Ìnstead of `square.setAttribute('onmouseover','getRandomColor()')` you need to use AddEventListener, like this: `square.addEventListener('mouseover',getRandomColor)`.

** Edit: I made the code do what you wanted **

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RocketSeat - Challenge 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
        <button onclick="MakeSquare()" style="margin-top: 100px;">Make a square</button>

    </body>
    <script>
        function MakeSquare(){
            const square = document.createElement('div')
            const elementBody = document.querySelector('body')
            square.style.backgroundColor ='red'
            square.style.width = '50px'
            square.style.height = '50px'
            square.style.marginTop= '50px'
            square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => giveSquareRandomColor(square));
            elementBody.appendChild(square)
        }

        function giveSquareRandomColor(square) {
            var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            var color = "#";
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
                }
            square.style.backgroundColor = color // I know this is not gonna work - I just put here to give the idea. 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```